# Time increase when offline SetInterval jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario according to which when the user user is online then at every 3 or 4 sec an request is sent to the server, but the problem start when the user go offline is that scenario I want to increase the time of setinterval method of jquery I have written the code for it, but no success yet:-

My code is something like this

```
var interval= function(){
      if(hasInternets()){
          var inter= 15000;
          return inter;
      }
      else
          {
          var inter= 15000;
          inter+= 15000;
          return inter;
          }
  };
  setInterval( function(){
        if (hasInternets()) {
// here I am doing something
            }   
}, interval());
```

hasInternet method check the internet connection.

So if you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the main aim of that function? What does it do?

Comment: it is what we called exponential backoff and the use of it is when you go offline and when you are offline you want to increase the time of the ajax request to the server so that there is no unnecessary hit from the client end.

Answer (score 0):

Since function in JavaScript are objects, you can assign `inter` as field to that object that will be stored between function calls:

```
var interval = function(inter) {
        if (!interval.inter) {
            interval.inter = 15000;
        }
        if (hasInternets()) {
            return interval.inter;
        } else {
            interval.inter += 15000;
            return interval.inter;
        }
    };
setInterval(function() {
    if (hasInternets()) {
        // here I am doing something
    }
}, interval());
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` is called just once with the interval you initially pass as the second argument. It **does not** re-evaluate the interval after each execution.

To solve this, you can use `setTimeout()` instead with a different interval depending on conditions.

```
var interval= function() {
    return hasInternets() ? 15000 : 30000;
};
function doStuff() {
    if (hasInternets()) {
        // ...
    }

    // recalculate interval and continue
    setTimeout(doStuff, interval());
}
setTimeoue(doStuff, interval()); // start it off
```

Comment: thanks techfoobar for your solution,but I also have a solution for it need your points on my solution.

    var counter = 1000;
    var myFunction = function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    if(hasInternet()){
        counter += 2000;
    console.log("testing for exponential")
    console.log(counter)
    }
        interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);
    }
    var interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);

Comment: @railsman - Yes this should work too. But since you are cancelling the `setInterval()` and restarting it every time, `setTimeout()` would do just as well.